# PHP show odbc_fetch_row for 50 records then show X+50

Tags: php, sql

I dabble in php, and I am doing some display screens for our office. Mainly SQL (some MSSQL and now DB2) selections that are formatted and shown on a 40" monitor in portrait.

I do have a problem, hence the question :)

I can comfortably show 50 records on a screen. Unfortunately the records can vary from 1 to 300 during the day (order/shipping data).
I am looking for a dynamic way of showing the first 50 records for 30 seconds, then the next 50 for 30 seconds etc... then at the end of the loop refresh the page to pull the new data-set and start from 1.

Basic script that I have (unformatted) is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta content="en" http-equiv="Content-Language">
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<title>Shipping</title>
<style type="text/css">
.auto-style1 {
    border-left: 1px solid #C0C0C0;
    border-right-style: solid;
    border-right-width: 1px;
    border-top: 1px solid #C0C0C0;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
text-align: center;
}
.auto-style2 {
    border-left-style: solid;
    border-left-width: 1px;
    border-right: 1px solid #C0C0C0;
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-top-width: 1px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #C0C0C0;
text-align: center;
}
</style>
</head>

<?php
$server="Driver={Client Access ODBC Driver (32-bit)};System=server";
$user="username"; #a valid username that will connect to the DB
$pass="password"; #a password for the username

$conn=odbc_connect($server,$user,$pass); #you may have to remove quotes


#Check Connection
if ($conn == false) {
echo "Not able to connect to database...<br>";
}

#Query the Database into a result set - 
$result=odbc_exec($conn,"
select * from table");

if (!$result)
  {exit("Error in SQL");}

echo "<table class='auto-style2' style='width: 800px'><tr><td class='auto-style1'>Shipment Number</td><td class='auto-style1'>Shipment Date</td><td class='auto-style1'>End customer order number</td><td class='auto-style1'>Qty</td></tr>";


while (odbc_fetch_row($result))
  {

  $b=odbc_result($result,1);
  $c=odbc_result($result,2);
  $d=odbc_result($result,3);
  $e=odbc_result($result,4);

  echo "    <tr><td class='auto-style1'>$b</td>";
  echo "        <td class='auto-style1'>$c</td>";
  echo "        <td class='auto-style1'>$d</td>";
  echo "        <td class='auto-style1'>$e</td></tr>";

  }
echo "</table>";

#close the connection
odbc_close($conn);
?>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Hi Dan, no error. The page displays all records, what I am looking for is how to show 50 records for 30 seconds, then the next 50. If there are no more records, then start from fresh, with a newly refreshed dataset.

Comment: You need to add a `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` to the query and a redirect (`<meta refresh`) to the site itself with a parameter one which *page* you're at. Simple as that.